# C# socket ReceiveAsync with await pattern not being called

Tags: c#, sockets, async-await, .net-5

I have a socket that I'm using to receive data. My code was originally the below

```
var receiver = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
var receiveEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
receiver.Connect(receiveEndPoint);

var bytes = new byte[1024];
int bytesRec = receiver.Receive(bytes);
var response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
```

This worked as expected. However, I'd like to change this to use the async await pattern. So I changed using `Receive` to using `ReceiveAsync` as per below.

But the `ReceiveAsync` never finishes awaiting. I'm guessing it is something to do with the `SocketFlags` but it's unclear what I should be using here so I went with `None`.

```
int bytesRec = await receiver.ReceiveAsync(bytes, SocketFlags.None);
```

What do I need to do to get this method to return?

Comment: It will return when the other party sends data of when the socket is closed

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: It will still "block" the current execution.

Answer (score 0):

The sender wasn't closing the socket and so the data wasn't being sent. Closing socket correctly now and issue is resolved and working as expected.